# Compensation for Confiscated Goods

Tags: united-kingdom

The U.K. government famously compensated former slaveholders when slavery was abolished. Was that a legal / constitutional requirement? Would the same apply today?

Comment: You mean whether somebody would be compensated if they let their slaves free? That souds silly, since it would reward people for doing something stricly illegal.

Answer (score 6):

The claim (see below) is that the compensation part of the British legislation abolishing slavery, which was hitherto not unlawful, came about to improve support for / reduce opposition to the legislation abolishing slavery. (Other states compensated slave-owners, perhaps for similar reasons - it is called '[compensated emancipation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compensated_emancipation)'.)

So yes, in that context the compensation was a legal requirement and apparently a political necessity.

Now that slavery is illegal, the UK is not obliged to compensate contemporary slaveowners any more than it is obliged to compensate people who unlawfully held property later confiscated by the authorities, such as illicit drugs or weapons.

In terms of property that has been legal to privately own that the government ostensibly wants to use for public benefit, the verb is 'to expropriate' (not 'confiscate'): to deprive a person of their private property for public use ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/expropriate)). Depending on the legal jurisdiction this is a power of a state, government or local authority, named for example '[compulsory purchase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compulsory_purchase_in_England_and_Wales)' or '[eminent domain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eminent_domain)'. Usually this pertains to land.

In principle and generally speaking, if a government wants to build a public road, railway, housing, Olympic Village etc, on land that happens to be privately owned, the government can do so but it's not right to simply deprive the owner of the land, the owner ought to be fairly compensated for their loss.

---

[Wikipedia on Britain compensating slave owners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slave_Compensation_Act_1837) (my emphasis):

> ... The Slavery Abolition Act 1833 (3 & 4 Will. 4. c. 73) contained provision for payments to slave owners in Cape of Good Hope, Mauritius, and the Virgin Islands as compensation for their loss of property in order **to persuade them to allow the legislation to be passed**. The Slave Compensation Act 1837 widened the compensation to cover the owner of any African slave in any colony. ...

Cites [Bank of England's Staff Working Paper No. 1,006](https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/working-paper/2022/the-collection-of-slavery-compensation-1835-43) (my emphasis):

> ... On 28 August 1833 Parliament passed legislation that abolished slavery within the British Empire, emancipating more than 800,000 enslaved Africans. **As part of the compromise that helped to secure abolition, the British government agreed a generous compensation package** of £20 million to slave-owners for the loss of their ‘property’. ...

Comment: And, am I right to understand that this right to compensation is simply the common law default that can be overridden by clear language in a statute? That is the situation in Canada, which I believe followed UK law on this point.

Comment: @Jen in Australia, Commonwealth appropriation must be compensated because that’s a Constitutional requirement. The States are not so bound but they compensate anyway.

Comment: In _A-G v De Keyser's Royal Hotel_ [1920] AC 508 it was argued but rejected that the Crown could take land without compensation - no such exercise of the prerogative power post-1688 was documented, and the entire topic had been replaced by statute law in any case. These days, the Civil Contingencies Act 2004 allows taking property without compensation in an emergency, which shows that a statute could authorize this (albeit that power hasn't been used, let alone challenged in court).

Comment: @alexg that's the judgment that roots the courts' position in Canada too. The Supreme Court of Canada followed this language from *De Keyser's Royal Hotel*: "unless the words of the statute clearly so demand, a statute is not to be construed so as to take away the property of a subject without compensation."